# Call the constructor from another constructor of the same class

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, virtual

I'm having several problems in developing this program I do not understand why.

1) I can not call the constructor method of the class Terna, with the other two methods manufacturers and pass the values ​​to my interests. Line 21 and 22.

2) Should I create two objects using the 'nuovo' method.
In class A should create an object of type B.
In class B should I create an object of type A.
Ritornandoli.
In the new method, and you virtual.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>
#define DEF 50
using namespace std;

class B;

class Terna{

    protected:
        int * xyz;

    public:
        Terna(int _x,int _y,int _z){
            xyz = new int[3];
            xyz[0] = _x;
            xyz[1] = _y;
            xyz[2] = _z;
        }
        Terna(int _x) : Terna(_x, _x, _x){}
        Terna(int *_x) : Terna(_x[0],_x[1],_x[2]){}
        string toString(){
            stringstream t;
            t << "[ " << xyz[0] << ", " << xyz[1] << ", " << xyz[2] <<" ]";
            return t.str();
        }
        virtual int m() = 0;
        //virtual Terna nuovo(Terna *_t) = 0;

};

class A : public Terna{

    public:
        A(int _x) : Terna(_x){}
        A(int *_x) : Terna(*_x){}
        Terna nuovo(Terna *_t){
            B * b = new B(m()+xyz[0]);
            return b;
        }
        int m(){
            int m = 0;
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
                m += xyz[i];
            return m/3;
        }
        string toString(){
            stringstream s;
            for(int i=0;i<m();i++)
                s << 'x';
            return "A:" + Terna::toString()+" "+s.str();
        }
};

class B : public Terna{

    public:
        B(int _x) : Terna(_x){}
        B(int *_x) : Terna(*_x){}
        Terna nuovo(Terna *_t){
            A * a = new A(m()-xyz[1]-xyz[2]);
            return a;
        }
        int m(){
            int max = 0;
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
                if(max<xyz[i])
                    max = xyz[i];
            return max;
        }
        string toString(){
            stringstream s;
            for(int i=0;i<m();i++)
                s << 'x';
            return "B:" + Terna::toString()+" "+s.str();
        }
};


int manin(){

    srand(2999888);
    Terna * vett[DEF];
    int * x = new int[3];
    int max = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<DEF;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++) 
            x[j] = rand()%10;
        if(rand()%2 == 1) vett[i] = new A(x);
        else vett[i] = new B(x);

        if(max<vett[i]->m())
            max = vett[i]->m();
    }

    Terna * vett2[DEF/2];
    vett2[0] = vett[0];
    vett2[1] = vett[DEF];

    for(int i=2;i<DEF;i++)
        vett2[i] = vett2[i-1]->nuovo(vett2[i-2]);

    return 0;
}
```

```
C:\Users\angel\Desktop\method\method7.cpp   In constructor 'Terna::Terna(int)':
19  35  C:\Users\angel\Desktop\method\method7.cpp   [Warning] delegating constructors only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
C:\Users\angel\Desktop\method\method7.cpp   In constructor 'Terna::Terna(int*)':
20  43  C:\Users\angel\Desktop\method\method7.cpp   [Warning] delegating constructors only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
C:\Users\angel\Desktop\method\method7.cpp   At global scope:
36  9   C:\Users\angel\Desktop\method\method7.cpp   [Error] invalid abstract return type for member function 'Terna A::nuovo(Terna*)'
7   7   C:\Users\angel\Desktop\method\method7.cpp   [Note] because the following virtual functions are pure within 'Terna':
26  15  C:\Users\angel\Desktop\method\method7.cpp   [Note] virtual int Terna::m()
C:\Users\angel\Desktop\method\method7.cpp   In member function 'Terna A::nuovo(Terna*)':
36  9   C:\Users\angel\Desktop\method\method7.cpp   [Error] invalid abstract return type for member function 'Terna A::nuovo(Terna*)'
7   7   C:\Users\angel\Desktop\method\method7.cpp   [Note] since type 'Terna' has pure virtual functions
37  4   C:\Users\angel\Desktop\method\method7.cpp   [Error] 'B' was not declared in this scope
37  8   C:\Users\angel\Desktop\method\method7.cpp   [Error] 'b' was not declared in this scope
37  16  C:\Users\angel\Desktop\method\method7.cpp   [Error] expected type-specifier before 'B'
37  16  C:\Users\angel\Desktop\method\method7.cpp   [Error] expected ';' before 'B'
C:\Users\angel\Desktop\method\method7.cpp   At global scope:
59  9   C:\Users\angel\Desktop\method\method7.cpp   [Error] invalid abstract return type for member function 'Terna B::nuovo(Terna*)'
7   7   C:\Users\angel\Desktop\method\method7.cpp   [Note] since type 'Terna' has pure virtual functions
C:\Users\angel\Desktop\method\method7.cpp   In member function 'Terna B::nuovo(Terna*)':
59  9   C:\Users\angel\Desktop\method\method7.cpp   [Error] invalid abstract return type for member function 'Terna B::nuovo(Terna*)'
7   7   C:\Users\angel\Desktop\method\method7.cpp   [Note] since type 'Terna' has pure virtual functions
61  11  C:\Users\angel\Desktop\method\method7.cpp   [Error] invalid conversion from 'A*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
19  3   C:\Users\angel\Desktop\method\method7.cpp   [Error] initializing argument 1 of 'Terna::Terna(int)' [-fpermissive]
61  11  C:\Users\angel\Desktop\method\method7.cpp   [Error] cannot allocate an object of abstract type 'Terna'
7   7   C:\Users\angel\Desktop\method\method7.cpp   [Note] since type 'Terna' has pure virtual functions
C:\Users\angel\Desktop\method\method7.cpp   In function 'int manin()':
100 26  C:\Users\angel\Desktop\method\method7.cpp   [Error] 'class Terna' has no member named 'nuovo'
```

Comment: Distill the code into the smallest block that shows the error, and post that here

Comment: if anyone not knowing about error then don't down vote him.OP posted code as well error.So what else you want

Comment: @JKB: A minimal example, as required by both this website's policy and common bloody sense. Oh, and, _a question_.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit `minimal example` but here OP posted whole code.So any one compile on own machine to reproduce error.So what batter you want from OP.might be want to remote access of OP machine :).So still some one bloody sense down vote OP.

Comment: You could have read the warning at get rid of it `[Warning] delegating constructors only available with -std=c++11`

Comment: @JKB: You're missing the point. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to find out why a minimal example is useful and expected. It's not that we can't compile the OP's code — it's that, right now, he's essentially asking us to do his divide-and-conquer debugging _for him_, and that's not what SO is for. SO is not a personal debugging helpdesk. Besides which, if the OP had done enough of his pre-asking work, he'd _already have a minimal example_; this shows that he should still be working through the problem on his own. Thanks.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit You are absolutely  right.Thanks to point me :)

Comment: @JKB: Well, I could also claim that the question shows little effort. What is so hard to understand from *delegating constructors only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11* or *because the following virtual functions are pure within 'Terna': virtual int Terna::m()*... I don't know, but it seems that the user typed, it failed to compile and he just dumped the error here for others to *read*. Reading and understanding error messages is an important part of the business, and this does not show effort on that part, really.

Answer (score 2):

If you do that `virtual int m() = 0` inside a class you have a abstract class, Abstract classes cannot be used to instantiate objects, but it can be used to create pointers, so `nuovo` should return a pointer to `Terna`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an instance of a `Terna` class due to `virtual int m() = 0;`

Modify `nuovo` to return a pointer, not an object.

and of course, compile with `-std=c++11`

Also, you cannot use the incomplete class `B` ... while in `A::nuovo()` ... (you just forward declare with `class B;` )

Recommendation: split the file up properly in `.h`, `.cpp` and then your problems should be solved.

Answer (score 0):

The delegating constructors seem allowed. You only get a warning about it.

The first error is about the fact that you're returning an instance of Terna. It is not allowed. It is considered an abstract class, since you have a pure virtual (abstract in OO terms) method. You can never have a concrete instance of that.

You should use a pointer to Terna instead.

Also note that your main function is called manin. Typo?

Also note that you're using B before it is 'seen' by the compiler. That's why you're getting the

```
[Error] 'B' was not declared in this scope
```